# date() does not respect the current locale, while strftime() does

Tags: php, date, locale, strftime

This is the full content of my test file:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
echo date('F'); // => "February" (wrong)
echo strftime('%B'); // => "Februar" (correct)
?>
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? I have already verified that the `de_DE` locale is installed, using `locale -a` in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date().

So what you're seeing is expected behavior. Use `strftime()` for locale formatted dates, and `date()` when that is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that `date()` is not ideal when dealing with localized month names, but the library that I'm using is using `date()` over `strftime()`, and their suggestion is to use `setlocale()` to get the correct month names. So I'm stuck with `date()` unfortunately. :(

Comment: You might need to modify that library if you need this to work correctly. Or extend it by wrapping your own code around it.

Comment: Hm, the wording in the PHP manual is a bit unclear. Do you think it's IMPOSSIBLE to get a properly localized text string out of `date()`? I'm reading it more like a suggestion...

Comment: I don't see any examples on that page that would indicate it was possible but with a little creativity (i.e. hacking) it might be possible.